# Asymptotics of a function from its Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

My question is: given a Fourier transform $\hat f$ of a function $f$, is it possible to estimate its asymptotic behaviour without performing the inverse transform?

Let me give a concrete example.

Suppose, a spherically symmetric real-valued function $f(x)$ (with $x\equiv|{\bf x}|$ and ${\bf x}\in \mathbb R^3$) has a Fourier transform of the following form
$$
\hat f(k) = \frac{P_m(k)}{Q_n(k)}
$$
where $P_m(k)$ and $Q_n(k)$ are certain polynomials of $k=|{\bf k}|$, and the degrees $m$ and $n$, some integer numbers less than 10. In the general case, it is quite hard (if at all possible) to calculate the inverse Fourier transform. However, suppose, we need not the function $f(x)$ itself, but only wish to determine its asymptotic behaviuor for $x\rightarrow \infty$. Such situations typically occur in physics, for instance in field theory, where the asymptotics of a field $f(x)$ is oftentimes significantly more relevant than the exact expression for this field.

So, can we extract any information about asymptotic behaviour of $f(x)$  form the Fourier image $\hat f(k)$ itself, without performing the complicated (and sometimes even technically impossible) inverse transform?

Thank you!

Comment: if $\hat{f}(k)\propto k^p$ for small $k$, then $f(x)$ has for large $|x|$ the asymptotic $|x|^{-p-3}$.

Comment: The general principle is that the asymptotics of the function depend on the smoothness of the FT and vice versa.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I don't think this works (for example, take $\widehat{f}=1/(1+|k|^2)$, then $p=0$). (You perhaps had the much less general evaluation $\widehat{|k|^{-\alpha}}=c|x|^{\alpha-d}$ in mind.)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! If possible, please,  hint where one could read about the relevant theorems. I have found a post on a similar topic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794619/asymptotic-behaviours-from-fourier-transforms, but nothing more or less rigorous has been indicated there. Any help with the literature will be highly appreciated! Thank you guys!

Comment: @jonathanwolf: The way to make this precise is to just integrate by parts in the Fourier inversion formula.

Comment: There is a large literature relating asymptotic behavior with the properties of Laplace transform. As the Laplace transform is essentially Fourier transform on the imaginary line, this should be useful for physicists. To begin with, you may look into Doetsch, Anleitung zum praktischen Gebrauch der Laplace-Transformation (there is a Russian translation). The asymptotic behavior is essentially determined by the zeros of $Q$ is the complex $k$-plane.

Comment: My favourite reference for this kind of thing is: K. Soni, R. P. Soni, *Slowly varying functions and asymptotic behavior of a class of integral transforms: I, II, III*. J. Anal. Appl. 49 (1975), 166–179, 477–495, 612–628. Links: [I](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82187291.pdf), [II](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82664942.pdf), [III](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82393734.pdf). This is somewhat different from what Alexandre Eremenko suggested above, more general than polynomials, but less detailed, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments!